# Conditional operator inside C++ fibonacci lambda

Tags: c++, function, lambda

While checking how to implement a recursive lambda function I stumbled upon [this](https://artificial-mind.net/blog/2020/09/12/recursive-lambdas) solution

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto fr = [] (int n, auto&& fr) {
        if (n < 2)
            return n;
        else
            return fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr);
    };
    auto fib = [&fr] (int n) {return fr(n,fr);};
    
    int n = 10;
    cout << "fib(" << n << ") = " << fib(n) << endl;
}
```

Which works great. However, trying a subtle change such as

```
auto fr = [] (int n, auto&& fr) {
        return n < 2 ? n : fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr);
    };
```

Gives the following compilation error:

```
error: use of 'main()::<lambda(int, auto:1&&)> [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(int, auto:1&&)>&]' before deduction of 'auto'
```

What I'm missing?

Also, I though of another way of making this code more compact, as having two lambdas seems a bit messy. It is possible to execute a lambda immediately after declaration by placing a parentheses after it, so would it be possible to do something like this?

```
auto fib = [] (int n) {
        auto fr = [] (int n, auto&& fr) {
            return n < 2 ? n : fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr);
        }(n, fr);
    };
```

This way, when the function fib is called, the function fr is declared and called automatically. However, I'm new to lambdas and don't know if the syntax is even close to making sense...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has to do with the return type deduction. With the explicit `if` statement the compiler will parse `return n` first, deducing the return type to be `int`. That can't be done with the conditional expression, because when you call the function `fr`, the return type still haven't been deduced. It's unknown if its return type is compatible with the `int` from `n`.

Comment: In the first case, the return type can be inferred from the statement `n;`. In the second, it can only be inferred by by analyzing the expression `n < 2 ? n : fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr)`. The type of that expression depends on `fr`. The compiler is choking because in the process of inferring the return type of the lambda, it's encountering that very type.

Answer (score 7):

This is a subtle chicken vs. egg problem.

```
[] (int n, auto&& fr) { ... }
```

Before this closure can be used its return type must be deduced.

```
 return n;
```

`n` is an `int`. This means that the closure's `return` type can be deduced as an `int`. The `return` statement serves to deduce the closure's return type.

```
return n < 2 ? n : fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr);
```

The type of this ternary expression can only be determined by figuring out what integer promotion rules apply here, if any. One of the expressions is `n`, and `int`, and the other expression's type is ...what exactly? It's unknown. Fail.

The solution is is to explicitly define the closure's return type:

```
    auto fr = [] (int n, auto&& fr) -> int {
            return n < 2 ? n : fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr);
    };
```

Comment: But if at least one side of the if else block is of type int, can't the compiler deduce that if the other side is not possible to infer it must match the side that is already known?

Comment: The better solution in presence of C++23 would be deduced `this`: 
```c++
 auto fr = [] (this auto fr, int n) -> int {
            return n < 2 ? n : fr(n-1,fr) + fr(n-2,fr);
    };
    int fib5=fr(5);
```

Comment: No, the compiler cannot deduce that. If the other side, for example, turns out to be a `long` the ternary expression would evaluate to a `long` and not `int`.